Exiting full screen with Maui MediaElement make app crash
I use Shell for navigation between pages. There are two pages, the details page and the video page. The details page will navigate to the video page. In addition to the MediaElement, the video page also has a CollectionView for the user to select a specific episode to be played.
<!--DetailPage.xaml-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    ...
    xmlns:vm="...ViewModels"
    ...>
    ...
    <Grid>
        <CollectionView ... ItemsSource="{Binding Videos}">
            ...
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame ...>
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnGoVideoPageCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:DetailViewModel}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        ... 
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
        ...
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>


//DetailViewModel.cs

...
namespace ...ViewModels
{
    public partial class DetailViewModel
    {
        ...
        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task OnGoVideoPageAsync(Video video)
        {
            
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("VideoPage", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Video", video } });
            
        }
    }
}


<!--videoPage.xaml-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    ...
    Unloaded="ContentPage_Unloaded">
    ...
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="228" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <toolkit:MediaElement
                x:Name="media"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                ShouldAutoPlay="True"
                ShouldKeepScreenOn="True"
                ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
                Source="{Binding VideoUrl}"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                ZIndex="1" />
            <CollectionView ... ItemsSource="{Binding Video.Episodes}">
                ...
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame ...>
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding SetVideoUrlCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:VideoViewModel}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
         
                            ...
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                 </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
             </CollectionView>
        </Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>


//VideoPage.xaml.cs
...

namespace ...Views;

public partial class VideoPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly VideoViewModel _vm;

    public VideoPage(VideoViewModel vm)
    {
        _vm = vm;
        this.BindingContext = _vm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ContentPage_Unloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        media.Handler?.DisconnectHandler();
    }

}


//VideoViewModel.cs
...

namespace ...ViewModels
{
    public partial class VideoViewModel : ObservableObject, IQueryAttributable
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Video? _video;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public string _videoUrl = string.Empty;

        public async void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
        {
            Video = query["Video"] as Video;
            ...
            await Task.Run(() => Video!.LoadEpisodesAsync());
            ...
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task SetVideoUrlAsync(Episode episode)
        {
            ...
            VideoUrl = episode.VideoUrl;
        }
    }
}
    


On this basis, users click the full-screen button to enter the full-screen mode to watch videos, and when they don't want to watch, they will exit the full-screen through the full-screen gesture of Android phone —— side slide back or click the system's back button.
The result I expect is that the MediaElement exits full screen and is still playing, and the page is still a video page. But the reality is that the ContentPage_Unloaded () method of the video page is called, the video resource is released, and the MediaElement stops playing but magically remains in full-screen mode.
I guess I've gone back from the video page to the details page, but I can't see it because of the full screen coverage of the MediaElement. At this point, if I click on the full screen button of MediaElement, the software will crash.
The only normal operation that doesn't crash the software is that I first exit the full screen by clicking the full screen button of MediaElement, which is just as expected, and then I slide back or click back to return to the details page normally from the video page.
I want to know if anyone and II want to know if anyone has the same problem as me and if there is a good solution. I would be grateful if you could share it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please add the relevant code about the VideoPage and the jump logic between different pages.

I've uploaded the relevant code and looking forward to someone help

Do you also encounter this problem on the Android platform?

Yes, I haven't tried it on other platforms, but that's the case with Android

What is your Android emulator version? Does it have the same issue on other versions of Android?
